# I want to style button in css but the button class not working when I target this from css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

I have done this code for navbar with reactjs, but the button class is not working. I tried with basic button styling but it's not working. I'm new with this so I can't find the wrong part.

the jsx file->>
[This is the jsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uED6T.png)

The css file->>
[This is the css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8EV9.png)

Final Output->>
[Final webpage view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUkto.png)

I want to style the button but when I target button class from css it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you are styling the div, if you want to style the button add the classname to button `<button className='button'>Contact</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Add the class: "button" to the  tag.

Your designs are going to the div container, and not the actual button